Finding lowest low between to given bar indexes
I have two arrays that track the higher highs in a market, one tracks the price at the high and the other tracks the bar index. I am having trouble of finding a solution of what I want to do when a higher high is detected. As of now, when a higher high is found, I am able to find the the two bar indexes (previous high and the current high).
I have tried subracting the current high's bar index by the previous highs index, giving me a "lookback" for how many bars have past. I then tried running a for loop to search how ever many bars since the previous high using ta.lowest(low, loopback) but it seems pinescript doesn't like running ta. in if statements.
What would be a way to find lows or high between two bar indexes?
